# Unable to replace String containing special characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace all special characters with whitespace but I am unable to replace **x** :

```
String search = "640×20141007151608@#$%$20141008104817.jpeg";
String newSearch = search.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}&&[^_]]", "");
System.out.println(newSearch);
```

output : 640×2014100715160820141008104817jpeg

Comment: whitespace or no space?

Comment: @Vks I dont have any problem with white or no space. but I want replace this "x" character in file name to be replaced.

Comment: but your output has `x` ?

Comment: yes. it is replacing all special characters except "x".

Comment: Well "x" is not really that special!

Comment: @JamesAnderson - It's an × (like a multiplication) not an x.

Answer (score 4):

I use the logic below:

```
String newSearch = search.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]","");
```

That is, remove anything that is not a number or a digit. Is this what you wanted ?

Comment: @Rv15 this will `.` of `.html` as well.Is dat intended?

Answer (score 0):

```
[^0-9a-zA-Z\.]
```

Try this.Repalce by ``.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/51